# Find a CheckBoxList item by its value within many CheckBoxLists - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have many `CheckBoxList` in my page. Is it possible to search for individual `ListItems` by their value from the Code Behind?

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <h4>Ski</h4>
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ski" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Text="Hauts" Value="43" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Bas" Value="45" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Sous-vêtements" Value="89" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <h4>Ski de fonds</h4>
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="skidefonds" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Text="Hauts" Value="42" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Bas" Value="46" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Sous-vêtements" Value="90" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
To add more precision on the question: How to set the `ListItem` which as a value of `46` to Selected, without knowing which `CheckboxList` it belongs.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [recursive method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion) like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FindValue(this);
}

private void FindValue(Control ctrls)
{
     foreach (Control c in ctrls.Controls)
     {
         if (c is CheckBoxList)
         {
                CheckBoxList ff = c as CheckBoxList;
                for (int i = 0; i < ff.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if ((string)ff.Items[i].Value == "46")
                    {
                         ff.Items[i].Selected = true;
                    }
                }
          }

         else FindValue(c);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  Based on your structure, you would simply do:

```
// Selected:
IList<ListItem> selected = skidefonds.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
     .Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
```

You can also expose the content through a *loop*.

```
foreach(var item in skidefonds.Items)
{
     // Item will have all the attributes.
}
```

You can expose the value by doing the following:

```
var result = skidefonds.Items.FindByValue("...");
```

Or you can access the attribute directly on your `item` as you iterate through the loop.

```
foreach(var item in skidefonds.Items)
     item.FindByValue("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all checkbox lists and then within that loop all list items looking for the one you want.

```
foreach(Control cbxList in this.Controls)
{
    if(cbxList is CheckBox)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cbxList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((string)cbxList.Items[i] == value)
            {
                cbxList.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ListItem> skiValues = ski.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(li => li == 'Search')
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var item=ski.Items.FindByValue("yourvalue");
```